# How to show message when no jTable row is selected?

Tags: java, jtable, jbutton

I have a jButton and when it is clicked currently I can select multiple rows and I am able to delete all of them. I am trying to make a message pop up if no row is selected to warn the user. I tried different things, but I couldn't manage it in the end unfortunately.

```
private void silButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    try {
        int[] selectedItems = jTable2.getSelectedRows();
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
            String cell = (jTable2.getModel().getValueAt(selectedItems[i], 0)).toString();
            System.out.println(cell);
            String query="DELETE FROM Musteriler WHERE id="+cell+"";
            PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            int rs = pst.executeUpdate();
        }

        loadTable();
        cleanFields();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply just test that `selectedItems` length is zero or not:

```
if(selectedItems == null || selectedItems.length() < 1) {
    showPopup();
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately it doesn't work, the program works as normally.

Answer (score 1):

API reference:

> `public int[] getSelectedColumns​()`

Returns:
an array of integers containing the indices of all selected columns, or an **empty** array if no column is selected.

Basically you should check if the `selectedItems` is empty and show your modal dialog.